# htaccess redirect url with anchor tag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a URL to a page with an anchor tag. The redirect works but how do I keep the original URL after the redirect rather than the redirected one.

I want to redirect `www.example.com/caves/` to `www.example.com/trips.html#caves`.

When I redirect I get the URL `www.example.com/trips.html#caves` but want it to keep `www.example.com/caves/`.

I have spent ages looking for answers but no luck, any help would be appreciated

Here is my code in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^Caves/(.*) /trips.html#Caves [NE,L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it can be done. Anchor is a client side directive and you can't "hide" it with server side rewrite (the browser can't jump to anchor if it doesn't see one), so the anchor has to be in address bar URL.

Comment: The use of the term "anchor tag" in this context would seem to be a bit of a misnomer. The OP is already "successfully" redirecting to the actual URL (with the desired URL in the anchor tag), but they require the redirect to be "hidden", ie. an _internal rewrite_ - which is normally possible. However, the caveat in this instance is the fragment identifier, which is not passed through in an internal rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how do I keep the original URL after the redirect rather than the redirected one.

You want an *internal rewrite*, as opposed to an *external redirect* - which is what you are currently doing with the use of the `R` (redirect) flag on the `RewriteRule`.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^Caves/(.*) /trips.html#Caves [NE,L,R]
> ```

Ordinarily you could simply remove the `R` flag to keep the original URL in the address bar. The request is *internally rewritten* to `/trips.html`.

However, the fragment identifier (ie. `#Caves` - or strictly everything *after* the `#`) is lost. The request is rewritten to `/trips.html`, not `/trips.html#Caves`. The fragment identifier is evaluated by the client, not the server and is no doubt being used by your client-side JavaScript to display the appropriate content. Because of the internal rewrite, the client-side JavaScript never gets to see the fragment identifier.

However, if you are internally rewriting the request (ie. `/Caves/` is still present in the address bar) then your client-side code doesn't need the `#Caves` fragment identifier. It can simply look at the original URL, ie. `/Caves/` instead. But this will require a small change to your client-side code.

(*Aside...* Note that you are using `Caves` (capital first letter) in your code, but referring to `caves` (all lowercase) in your description. The directive you have written is case-sensitive, so it should be `/Caves/`, not `/caves/` in your description?)